# Display Multi Select And TextField Value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a `multi-select` drop down and a `textfield (multiline)` component from `MUI V5`. What I want is

1. When I select the values from the drop down then the selected values should be displayed in the textfield area.
2. Now along with the this when the user types in the textfield then the selected names from the drop down should persist in the textfield along with the user typed text.
3. Also if the user goes to de-select or select another name from the drop down then the text that was typed by the user should be there in the textfield it should not got away.

Currently the challenge that I am facing is when I start to type in the textfield then the selected names from the drop down get repeatedly added to the textfield area.

I tried to use a different state just to display the selected names and typed text from the user but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong ?
Do I need to use a third state and synchronize it with the drop-down and textfield state ?
Please help !

Code :-

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import OutlinedInput from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

const names = [
  "Oliver Hansen",
  "Van Henry",
  "April Tucker",
  "Ralph Hubbard",
  "Omar Alexander",
  "Carlos Abbott",
  "Miriam Wagner",
  "Bradley Wilkerson",
  "Virginia Andrews",
  "Kelly Snyder",
];

function getStyles(name, personName, theme) {
  return {
    fontWeight:
      personName.indexOf(name) === -1
        ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
  };
}

export function Test() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);
  const [textFieldValue, setTextFieldValue] = React.useState([]);
  const [displayValue, setDisplayValue] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    setPersonName(typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value);
    //setDisplayValue([...newPersonName, ...textFieldValue].join(", "));
  };

  const handleTextFieldChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    setTextFieldValue(typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value);
    //setDisplayValue([...personName, event.target.value].join(", "));
  };
  console.log([...personName, ...textFieldValue]);

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-name-label">Name</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-multiple-name-label"
          id="demo-multiple-name"
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput label="Name" />}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {names.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem
              key={name}
              value={name}
              style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}
            >
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <TextField
        id="outlined-multiline-flexible"
        label="Multiline"
        multiline
        maxRows={4}
        onChange={handleTextFieldChange}
        // value={displayValue}
        value={[...personName, textFieldValue].join(", ")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Following is the codesandbox link
[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/romantic-shape-wzzn8z?file=%2Fsrc%2FTest.js%3A93%2C16&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpplvfwx00063b6hcxmk8zui%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpplvfwx00023b6hmmobmlel%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpplvfwx00033b6h7gl8b7ob%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpplvfwx00053b6hik2wh4as%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B51.4251132171283%252C48.5748867828717%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpplvfwx00023b6hmmobmlel%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpplvfwx00013b6h476ugxba%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq9l1h3m00023b6hldnw07zk%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A93%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A16%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A93%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A16%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FTest.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpplvfwx00023b6hmmobmlel%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq9l1h3m00023b6hldnw07zk%2522%257D%252C%2522clpplvfwx00053b6hik2wh4as%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpplvfwx00043b6hfalj1adm%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpplvfwx00053b6hik2wh4as%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpplvfwx00043b6hfalj1adm%2522%257D%252C%2522clpplvfwx00033b6h7gl8b7ob%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpplvfwx00033b6h7gl8b7ob%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)